# I need help on deciphering a compilation error

Tags: magento-2.1, static-content

I'm trying to perform a test compile, and I'm receiving a few errors during compilation.

Here is a copy of the system.log file that gets generated:

```
    [2016-11-22 05:28:44] main.CRITICAL: 
Compilation from source: 
frontend/xthemes/theme_default/en_US/css/email-fonts.less
.lib-colorfont is undefined in /home/user/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/xthemes/theme_default/en_US/css/source/_typography.less [] []

[2016-11-22 05:28:44] main.CRITICAL: Compilation from source: /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-fonts.less

Compilation from source: 
frontend/xthemes/theme_default/en_US/css/email-fonts.less
.lib-colorfont is undefined in /home/user/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/xthemes/theme_default/en_US/css/source/_typography.less [] []

[2016-11-22 05:28:44] main.CRITICAL: 
Compilation from source: 
frontend/xthemes/theme_supermarket_store/en_US/css/email-fonts.less
.lib-colorfont is undefined in /home/user/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/xthemes/theme_supermarket_store/en_US/css/source/_typography.less [] []

[2016-11-22 05:28:44] main.CRITICAL: Compilation from source: /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-fonts.less

Compilation from source: 
frontend/xthemes/theme_supermarket_store/en_US/css/email-fonts.less
.lib-colorfont is undefined in /home/user/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/xthemes/theme_supermarket_store/en_US/css/source/_typography.less [] []
```

So it seems like its missing .lib-colorfont, however it exists in the _extends.less file, but the odd part is that the email-fonts.less file doesn't exist at all.  I'm stumped on how to resolve this.

Any helps is appreciated!

Comment: run this command
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Just an FYI, that is the command I was running when I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you do not put _extends.less on the place before email-fonts.less so when compiles, it caused @.lib-colorfont undeclared error. Just move _extends.less on a upper place before  email-fonts.less and retry

Comment: So I am rather new to M2 theming and I'm just starting to wrap my brain around how this works. So the email templates are in the Luma theme, however, I have a _typography.less file in my theme's web/css/source folder, which is also where the _extends.less file exists where the appropriate css is stored.  For some odd reason, it doesn't seem like it finds the theme's _extends.less file.  I'm not sure why tbh.  The annoying part is that I cannot seem to find the reference file that calls all of these files together.

Comment: So, I've gone as far as downloading the server files, and the original files from this particular themes archive. The only changes that I can find using Code Compare are some color changes in the theme's original files.

Are there any settings that are stored in the database? or a cache of the compilation?

Comment: Did you enable the cache? If yes, it could cause this error even your less files modified. Clear cache then re-deploy. Of course, I'd suggest to use developer mode first.

Comment: I was in developer mode, and I had the cache disabled.

Answer (score 0):

So, somehow, 3 email files were delete from the theme's web/css folder. So it was attempting to fallback to the blank theme, which was then trying to load the _extends.less file which didn't have those references.

Once I recopied the 3 missing files from the original theme archive, the problem was resolved.

Man, what a rabbit down a hole to trace the actual problem.  This is one of those times where fall-back code layout is a problem.